# Is it possible for a sys admin to delete a chatter file from a user's personal library?

Tags: chatter, administration, file-storage

I read that Modify All Data should give Sys admins access to all chatter files, provided they are not in a personal library.

However we have users uploading lots of data to personal libraries (via mobile SDK API). Sys admins need to clear that out. How can they do that? Surely there must be a way for sys admins to delete files, otherwise how could sys admins reclaim file storage.

Strange thing is, I'm seeing this ability in the Web UI under Files/All Files (other users chatter files, can delete even though they are marked Personal library). However am not seeing those files when I use SOQL in the workbench, makes me wonder how I'm going to automate the deletion